# Entity Framework 5 not updating navigation properties in both entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have updated a project to use the new `Entity Framework` shipped with `VS2012`. However, I ran into some issues 'cause of which my code is throwing exceptions.

In the `VS2010` version of `Entity Framework`, I was able to create or modify an `Entity` and use its navigation properties before calling `SaveChanges()`

For example:
A Navigation property of a client having a collection of Invoices.

```
Client c = new Client();
Invoice I = new Invoice();
c.Invoices.Add(I);
```

I would then be able to use `Invoice.Client` somewhere in my code before actually saving it without issue. Now `Invoice.Client == null`.

Similarly in setting `I.Client = C`, `I` does not show up under `C.Invoices`

What am I missing here or is this just simply how `Entity Framework 5` is?

**EDIT**

In `VS2010`, I Created a new project, added the same `DataSource` and the following code worked as expected:

```
Client C = new Client();
C.Name = "Test";
Invoice I = new Invoice();
C.Invoices.Add(I);
MessageBox.Show(I.Client.Name);
```

Did the exact same thing in `VS2012` and no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your above example you aren't actually attached to the context.

Back-references for EF are only populated via a process called fixups which runs as a result of DetectChanges which in turn is triggered by (in your case) IDbSet<>.Add()

If you modify your code to attach Client to the context before adding an invoice to it you should see the expected behaviour

**EDIT:**

I haven't really used this feature with DB First (.edmx) but you can enable it by using the below model type in 2010.

This model type has been removed in 2012 as [STEs have been deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj613668). (Although my understanding is that they still work for backward compatibility so if you were to upgrade a project from 2010-2012 you would still be able to use that model)

[image: Self Tracking Entities]

Comment: Hi Luke, as per my edit above, in 2010 the code works as I expect, but the same code and data source do not in 2012. Adding the items into the context made no difference whatsoever

Comment: @Taylor check if you have self tracking entities on, which is an alternative to the EF tracking graph. Self tracking entities create a proxy entity which has overriden properties which can execute fixups on set. If you have this enabled in your old version but not your new this could explain the behavior

Comment: Thanks Luke, this is something i have never come across, how is self tracking entities enabled?